# Is there a simpler way to hide a message in text?

Tags: python, loops, replace, file-io

I'm a newbie in Python.  I have a sample.txt with random generated numbers, like:

```
19037221033587391092437079557028877692702595511401290586220309427782043275898955
13014634281984666840672700841593682750341042603005069133412414693645751888948174
56838541727973720849200844623086602683492491763746229651640999725476969534996546
12627011765843518895372932379406833789092525082734142624019628192647653889804387
```

---

As You see, my little program is replacing in a chosen place [char=1], in a selected [line=2], number with a letters from (input). Do you have any sugestions how to simplify it and make it more pythonic?

```
class MagicBox:
    def __init__(self, q=0):
        self.q = q

    def oldtxt(self, line):
        with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines()[line:line+1]:
                return line
        f.close()

    def newtxt(self, line, char, newchar):
        with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines()[line:line + 1]:
                x = (list(line))
                x[char] = newchar
                return ''.join(x)
        f.close()

    def replace(self, file, old, new):
        for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):
            line = line.replace(old, new)
            sys.stdout.write(line)

    def change(self, input, n, line, char, newchar):
        old_txt = oldtxt(line)
        new_txt = newtxt(line, char, newchar)
        for linia in fileinput.input("sample.txt", inplace=1):
            linia = linia.replace(old_txt, new_txt)
            sys.stdout.write(linia)

    def doIT(self, input, line=0, char=0, step=0):
        n = 0
        d = list(input)
        for t in range(1, len(input)+1):
            self.change(line, char, d[n])
            char += step
            n += 1


doIT("Big Brown Fox", 0, 5, 7)
```

Comment: The `range()` function allows you to specify the step as the third argument.

Comment: in this line |for y in range(1,len(input)+1):| step will only limit the number of iterations

Comment: `for y in range(1, len(input), step):`

Comment: Put code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: What is your question? If you've answered your own question, your answer belongs in the answers section. But please make sure your question is an actual question as described in [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Answer (score 1):

The following solution might be a bit complicated, but I'll explain how it works and you should be able to replace some of it with your own, more understandable code.

```
def change(data, word, step, line, start_index):
    data = [[char for char in line] for line in data.split("\n")]
    for index in range(start_index, len(word) * step, step):
        data[line][index] = word[index // step]
    return "\n".join(["".join(line) for line in data])

new_data = change(old_data, "MAGIC", 3, 2, 1)
print(new_data)
```

The first line takes the `data` variable, which is a string, and splits it up into a 2D array, in this case, an array of lines in the data which are arrays of the characters in that line (sorry if that doesn't make sense). If you're unfamiliar with single-line for loops, you could also split the data like so:

```
data = data.split("\n")
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i] = list(data[i])
```

Next, we make a loop that iterates through the indices that each letter in `word` need to inserted in `data`. If you were to print the range as a list, for this example it would look like `[1, 4, 7, 10, 13]`.

Then for each of those indices, we get the exact character in the list on the specified line, and change it to the corresponding letter in `"MAGIC"`.

Finally, the 2D array that has been edited, gets joined together again to become a string. And again, you can rewrite that similarly to how the first line can be rewritten, but reversed.

Comment: I understand everything. I will study you code to understand better the Py-Do - the pythonic way of Samurai :D. I You will be kind enough to see my solution (I'm learning Python only a month for now) and tell me what do you think about it.